# Should an observable that is properly bound to a view have at least 1 subscriber when calling getSubscriptionsCount

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to diagnose an issue, and this is the only thing that looks off. The initial template is populating with data, and the observable is in place, but there are no subscribers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, there should be at least one subscription so long as the bindings have been applied.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pS5e9/

```
var viewModel = {
    textInputValue: ko.observable()  
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("textInput"));

window.alert('Subscription count: ' + viewModel.textInputValue.getSubscriptionsCount());
```